# mySQL: LEFT JOIN without repeatition | any other idea to get this result in Python

Tags: python, mysql, django

It's the whole day I am trying to manage a SQL query:

```
SELECT  t1.id, 
        t2.name, 
        t3.pressure, 
        t4.therapy  
FROM tbl_user_details as t1
    LEFT JOIN tbl_user_details_2 as t2 ON (t2.id=t1.id)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pressure as t3 ON (t3.id=t1.id)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_therapy as t4 ON (t4.id=t1.id)
WHERE t1.id BETWEEN 1 and 9
```

that gives me the following result (each column comes from a *different table*):
[image]

as you can see, it does repeat the fields `id, name` and the last `pressure` in order to fill "otherwise blank spaces". I found several posts about this topic but none of the solution fitted for me.

I would like to get a result such as the following, indeed:
[image]

**My final goal:** process the resulting array and convert it as a csv to export the data.

I am working with Django-Python and at first I tried to organize the CSV programmatically starting from zero - then I thought about asking mySQL to get the hard work done. And it did, just with this problem.

As for me would it be great also to "merge" horizontally the records of each table given the same ID.

Any idea how I may try to solve this?

Thank you for your future help.

**EDIT 1**: I need to point out, in case it was not clear, I am not an expert SQL dev (several years without using it); I changed the original query.

Comment: And why on earth would you use 2 JOINS and also a `FROM tbl_user_details as t1, tbl_user_details_2 as t2` in the same query??

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE()) - 1992) Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: So what links T1 to T2 as you have not put that info in the where clause either

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting.  SQL returns complete rows.  Every row will have 4 fields, just as every line in your CSV will have 4 fields.  How do you expect to implement those "ghost" fields?  You can certainly produce a chart like your example, by scanning the rows and looking for the duplicates, but SQL won't do that.

Comment: @TimRoberts I expect to have blank (NULL) fields as it would be better and smaller file to be read by human (that is the aim I have been asked)

Comment: You will have to do that in your python code

Comment: @Soul -- That's just not how SQL works.  What you're asking for is "grouping" or "pivoting".  You do that in YOUR code.  There are no cases where you dump an SQL query directly to a user.  There's always code in there.

Comment: First: `FROM tbl_user_details as t1, tbl_user_details_2 as t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id` **why** do you join a table to itself ?  (without using JOIN syntax)

Comment: Seems rather odd that a user `id` and their `name` should be in different tables! And linked by the `id`, I mean what would make that a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY and then GROUP_CONCAT with newline seperator which lists all the different values.
It doesn't show up properly in markup but each 
 is a newline.
Please see the DBfiddle link below.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_user_details(
> id int, name varchar (25));
> insert into tbl_user_details values
> (1,'User 1');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_pressure (
> id int, pressure varchar(10));
> insert into tbl_pressure values
> (1,'120/80'),
> (1,'130/90'),
> (1,'140/95');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_therapy(
> id int,therapy varchar(10));
> insert into tbl_therapy values
> (1,'drug A'),
> (1,'drug B'),
> (1,'drug C'),
> (1,'drug D');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  t1.id, 
>         max(t1.name), 
>         group_concat(distinct
>              t3.pressure
>              SEPARATOR '\n') 
>              pressures, 
>         group_concat(distinct 
>              t4.therapy
>              SEPARATOR '\n')
>              therapies
> FROM tbl_user_details as t1
>     LEFT JOIN tbl_pressure as t3 
>     ON (t1.id=t3.id)
>     LEFT JOIN tbl_therapy as t4 
>     ON (t1.id=t4.id)
> GROUP BY
>  t1.id
> ```

> ```
> id | max(t1.name) | pressures                  | therapies                           
> -: | :----------- | :------------------------- | :-----------------------------------
>  1 | User 1       | 120/80<br>130/90<br>140/95 | drug A<br>drug B<br>drug C<br>drug D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cf5975a3ef17ba2e356346f1d96f715a)*

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This solution doesn't fit to my needs as it doesn't generate a multiline results. My final goal is to process the array parsing it row by row and transform it to csv